# How to calculate Age? SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to calculate age from this table?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBhs5.png)

I transfered data from dd.mm.yyy to yyyy-mm-dd.
Tried to use DATE_DIFF. But it doesn't take into account whether or not the birthday has come or gone.

```
SELECT 
  *,
  DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', birthday), YEAR) AS age
FROM Staff
```

for birthday date 1997-10-02 i have 26 instead 25

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. What’s the datatype of the birthday field?

Comment: STRING : 01.12.2000;
               02.10.1997

Comment: Does your database not support date types?
Or is this inherited code and data?
As with JSON use the appropriate types for data...this prevents problems like this.

To answer it your self.
Build test data ....build a gold result....
Run snippet until align.
Iterate().

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to have you here. However, your question might benefit from some improvements. Could you provide more context and be more specific about your issue? This will help you get better responses. Please read following guide: [How To: Write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Afterwards [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) your post and improve it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of it is to `compare months and dates` and whether to add 1 of not.

#### Query

```sql
WITH
birthday_dataset AS (
    SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', '03.09.1990') AS birth,
    UNION ALL SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', '04.09.1990') AS birth,
    UNION ALL SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', '05.09.1990') AS birth,
)
SELECT
    DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), birth, YEAR)
    + IF (
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE()) * 31 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE())
        > EXTRACT(MONTH FROM birth) * 31 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM birth)
        , 1, 0
    ) AS age,
FROM birthday_dataset
;
```

#### Results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way DATEDIFF normally works is that if the difference crosses the "end" of the defined date period it counts as 1 else it counts as zero.

For example, if the first day of the week is set to Sunday then the datediff in weeks between a Sat and the following Mon would be 1 (as Mon is is the next week) but Sun to Sat would be zero (in the same week).

Similarly, using datediff and year, the difference between '2022-12-31' and '2023-01-02' would be 1 (as it crosses the year end boundary) but the difference between '2023-01-02' and '2023-01-02' would be zero as it doesn't cross the year boundary - even though the actual difference in days in both examples is 1 day.

Based on this knowledge you can add/substract 1 from your datediff calculation (or leave it as it is), depending on your requirements